# Fail to parse Dynamic KeyValue pair JSON Using Custom JsonDeserializer GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I am tried to parse JSON using customDeserilizer for nesting Object

Here is my deserializer:

```
    class MapDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<String, String>> {

    public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                           JsonDeserializationContext  context){
        try {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject(); 
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue().getAsString();
                result.put(key, value);
            }
    //    }
            return result;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And i am using following line of code to register this deserializer

```
      Gson gson = new           GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(TaggedActorMap.class, new MapDeserializer()).create();
                    sActivityBean = gson.fromJson(result,
                            SimilarActivityBean.class);
```

Here is my POJO Class

```
public class TaggedActorMap implements Serializable {
private String key;
private  String value;
  }
```

I am getting following Error

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.setField(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:588)
  at     com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1
  .read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:119)
  at   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter
  .read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.
  read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.
  read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.
  read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.
  read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.
  read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.
  read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter
 .read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700)
```

Comment: A full stacktrace would be helpful

Comment: posted stacktrace @marthursson

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a mess. You need to make sure everything is tied together.

You're not referring to your `MapSerializer` (your `JsonDeserializer` implementation) anywhere. You're referring to something named `ArrayOfObjectsToMapDeserializer` when constructing your `GsonBuilder`. Also, when constructing the builder you refer to `TaggedActorMap.class`, but you're trying to deserialize a class named `SimilarActivityBean`.

You haven't registered any custom deserializer for `SimilarActivityBean`, so I'm guessing gson tries to deserialize the JSON using some default deserializer, failing because the data in the actual JSON doesn't match the fields in `SimilarActivityBean`

Comment: SimillarActivityBean is Base class and I need to implement JsonDeserializer only for TaggedActorBean which is nested in SimillarActivityBean , I dont know how to register deserializer with Classes,